# How to make dictionary from list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

My list:

```
list = ['name1', 'option1.1 value1.1', 'option1.2 value1.2', 'name2', 'option2.1 value2.1', 'option2.2 value2.2', 'option2.3 value2.3']
```

And i want create dictionary like this:

```
dict = {'name1':{'option1.1':'value1.1', 'option1.2':'value1.2'}, 'name2':{'option2.1': 'value2.1', 'option2.2':'value2.2', 'option2.3':'value2.3'}
```

I don't know how big is my list (numbers of names, options and values). Any idea?

Comment: What is your known info on each set of data?  You could have variable numbers of options per name, but the name will never be formatted `option.name` or `value.name` and the options and values will always have `option.` and `value.` on the front, correct?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Because you dont have a specific length to each set, you would have to loop over each item and act on the value containing 'name' to start a new key that is a new dictionary

Comment: How do you know which items in the list are "names" and which are "options"? Where did the data come from?

Comment: From where did you get `list` (which, incidentally is a really bad name for a `list` object)?

Comment: Give OP a break- why all the down votes? The question is clearly stated. And yes, dict and list are bad names, but well...

Answer (score 2):

with list and dict comprehension:

```
id=[b[0] for b in enumerate(lst) if 'name' in b[1]]+[None]
d={lst[id[i]]:dict(map(str.split,lst[id[i]+1:id[i+1]])) for i in range(len(id)-1)}
```

your original list was here named `lst`

This is perhaps not as readable as the answer by `@sr22222`, but perhaps it's faster, and a matter of taste.

Comment: I don't think this will work.  If name does not contain name, or there is more than 1 option/value pair per name, won't this choke?

Comment: I just tried it with a trivial example and it failed.  `lst = ['foon', 'fooopt.1 fooval.1', 'fooopt.2 fooval.2', 'barn', 'baropt.1 barval.1']` gave {} for b.  I think in the least, `if 'name' in b[1]` needs to be `if len(b[1]).split() == 1`.
Edit: even with that, it misses `barn`.

Comment: nm, I accidentally dropped the id.append(None).  And now I see how it works as well.  I missed the slice operation in the map when I was reading over it.  Clever.  +1

Answer (score 1):

Assuming name will always be a single token (also, don't use list and dict as variable names, as they are builtins):

```
result = {}
for val in my_list:
    split_val = val.split()
    if len(split_val) == 1:
        last_name = split_val[0]
        result[last_name] = {}
    else:
        result[last_name][split_val[0]] = split_val[1]
```

Note that this will choke if the list is badly formatted and the first value is not a name.

Comment: you can avoid the latter by providing a reasonable default for `last_name` (just add `last_name='noname'` before the loop). On the other side, "errors should never pass silently", you know

Comment: @thg435 I initially had a default, but I figured that really shouldn't work.  Some better error handling for the case would be good though.